# Can I create a Computed Column using EF6 code first

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

I have a requirement to create a calculated column in a database table using EF6 code first.  Below is the table definition I am trying to generate:

```
CREATE TABLE [Dim].[Account](
    [pkAccount] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Account] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [AccountDescription] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [AccountGroup] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [Chksum] AS checksum([Account],[AccountDescription],[AccountGroup])
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I want the `Chksum` column to calculate a value when a select is executed and not calculated externally and stored as a static value.

I have tried modifying the DbMigration as below using the `DefaultValueSql` property:

```
AlterColumn("Dim.Account", "Chksum", b => b.Int(false, false, defaultValueSql: "checksum([Account],[AccountDescription],[AccountGroup])"));
```

This returned the error `The name "[Account]" is not permited in this context`.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: can you try this `defaultValueSql: "checksum([Dim].[Account].[Account],[AccountDescription],[AccountGroup])")`

Comment: I think the problem with using `defaultValueSql` is where the value goes - in SQL Server there are two entries in column properties - `Default Value or Binding` (it tries to put it in here), or `Computed Column Specification` (this is where i want it to go)